# Is there a way to produce an "evaluate at" vertical bar that resizes properly in display formulae?

Tags: formatting, display

There are two examples of what I am talking about in this equation:
$$\displaystyle \left.\mathrm{d}\Phi\left(v\right)\right|_{p}\equiv\left.v^{\mu}\frac{\partial\Phi^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\lambda}}\right|_{\Phi\left(p\right)}.$$

They are the vertical bars that inform the reader what value is used for evaluation of the preceding expressions.

When I try to produce such a result, the bar resizes inappropriately.  I want this this for text and display equations, not form input.  Is there a way to accomplish what I am asking for?

Comment: Have you tried setting [`SpanMaxSize -> Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpanMaxSize.html) for the Cell you put the expression in?

Comment: Nope.  I have that set globally.

Comment: If, with that setting in place, I right click on the expression in your question here, select Show Math As > MathML Code, then copy that code and paste it into the Notebook, letting *Mathematica* interpret the result, I see basically the same expression.  Do you also?

Comment: Yes, but it will take some time to figure out which part of the Cell expression makes it work.  And then, how should it be input without jumping through hoops?

Comment: I was not suggesting that was a solution itself, rather a proof that *Mathematica* can display the expression, and therefore this question should be answerable.  I am not awake enough to give it a proper try however.

Comment: Please add input to play with and elaborate on "resizes inappropriately" (screenshot maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use an input alias? For example:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {
    "at" -> SubscriptBox[
        RowBox[{
            "\[SelectionPlaceholder]",
            StyleBox["\[RightBracketingBar]", FontFamily->"Times"]
        }],
        "\[Placeholder]"
    ]
};
```

And here is an animation producing your desired formula:

[image]

*(note that I modified the style sheet to adjust the [`ScriptLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScriptLevel), [`FontSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize) and [`FontFamily`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontFamily) of inline cells)*